# In a WPF project, how do I initialize my Window and controls and then jump into a main loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, loops, program-entry-point

Apologies if the question is poorly phrased, new to C#. I'm trying to make a text adventure. I've already written all the underlying logic, and decided to try and use a WPF for basic graphics. So I initialize the window with all the controls I need and then loop through my main loop until you trigger an exit. I initially tried putting the loop right after initializing the window.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Game.Logic();
}
```

This didn't really work well as the Window stopped initializing at all.
So I googled around a bit and tried using a Loaded Event. Once I did that, the Window pops up when I run the code, but none of the controls appear and the window is frozen. The same problem persisted when I tried to use a Loaded Event for the controls themselves. While there may be some kind of bug in my Game Loop, I think the Window should at least be able to initialize all its controls if I'm jumping into the Loop correctly. Would the right thing to do be to go into the App file and use a Loaded Event there? Or am I just completely out of line somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty far out of line.

By executing a tight loop on the UI thread, you are killing any chance of the UI *ever* updating, even if you got past your current roadblocks. As far as Windows is concerned; you are "frozen".

You need to run your logic loop on another thread and use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to get any UI updates (and **only** UI updates) back onto the UI thread. While typically not as useful in game contexts, also consider using the MVVM pattern with `Binding`s as its harder to fall into this trap.

For a text adventure, I would *strongly* recommend the MVVM pattern as all of your elements are easily represented as bound items/collections. Plus, it gets you into good modern development practices :)

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. So I need to start another thread somewhere that contains the logic loop. That sounds google-able. I know I should be using the MVVM pattern...I'll implement it, once I get things working at all.

Comment: You could also try to run your loop logic in a Tick event handler of a DispatcherTimer, which already runs in the UI thread.

Comment: @Clemens true, but if he is doing any intensive processing the UI thread would be locked up. I would probably avoid that route.

Comment: "if he is...", who knows? I wouldn't assume that without reason.

Comment: I'd also need to modify it a bit so I'm not running a tight loop as a tick event, else I'd just run into the same problem as before, right?

Comment: @PPFY Yes, you wouldn't want a tight loop in the event handler

Comment: I actually got everything running by multi-threading and Invoking for UI changes, in this case adding text to a flow document whenever appropriate in the text adventure. I do have a follow up question of sorts. How would I go around doing the reverse: So whenever I trigger an event in my UI thread, pass a string to my worker thread. I managed to get something working by creating a public variable in my window class that gets set to something at an event that the logic thread waits on to not be null, but that seems hacky and feels off somehow.

Comment: Typically the input would be bound, and then your View Model could send the data to the logic via a method call.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Background Worker, which will allow you to carry out UI updates using multi-threading to ensure your main thread remains responsive.

Comment: While this works; remember that direct UI manipulation **must** occur on the UI thread.